# Pass all variabes with given prefix to a compile command

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

From within a GNU makefile, is there a way to take all variables with a given prefix, and pass them as `-D` defines to a compile command?

For example, given that following variables exist:

```
DEFINE_FOO=cat
DEFINE_BAR=dog
```

Is there a way to automatically generate the string `-DFOO=cat -DBAR=dog` from within make such that it automatically picks up any variables added later with the prefix `DEFINE_`?

Answer (score 3):

If you use GNU make, you can do it like this:

```
CPPFLAGS += $(patsubst DEFINE_%,-D%,$(foreach V,\
                $(filter DEFINE_%,$(.VARIABLES)),$V=$($V)))
```